# Visual studio installation in Sharepoint 2016 Multi Server farm

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I am having Sharepoint 2016 on-premise environment in Multi Server Farm. I want to create custom solutions using Visual Studio 2015 and Infopath. Could someone tell me on which server I should install visual studio, Infopath ie. in Application server or Front end server or both?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter on which server you install it. The server just needs to be member of the SharePoint farm. If your InfoPath form does not contain any .NET code, then you can install it on your local computer and use it remotely.

But you should not use production servers for development. Deploying SharePoint solutions (WSP) and InfoPath forms (with code) restarts the IIS on all servers with Web Application role.